# Define database source in one location in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm transitioning a `SqlConnection` codebase over to `EF Core` for `UWP`. I'm wondering if there is a way to define the `optionsBuilder.UseSqlite` in one location as opposed to defining it in each context class or having a getter and using it the `OnConfiguring` method. Ideally I would rather not override the `OnConfiguring` method with build options if I didn't need to.

Here is the code/situation I'm referring to:

```
public class SearchTermContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<SearchTerm> SearchTerm { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        // i dont want to do this each time or use a global string getter
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=products.sqlite");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<SearchTerm>();
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Also I don't want to do this each time:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SearchTerm>();
```

Ideally I just want to define the `DBset`, if I do need options or need to override I can, but not if it isn't required.

Comment: It sounds like you have multiple context classes. In my opinion you can do two things. 1) Investigate if you really need all those existing context classes; in EF you have the option to add multiple DbSets to the the same context class 2) if you really need the multiple context classes you can work with an extra layer of inheritance. Define a new class MyGenericDbContext in which you define your specific implementation of OnConfiguring and OnModelCreating. This new MyGenericDbContext inherits from DbContext. All specific ContextClasses inherit from MyGenericDbContext